# Is a view's frame always set by the time `draw(_:)` is called?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I use the below code to curve the edge of a custom view.

```
/// Curves `self's` trailing edge.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    let path=UIBezierPath(ovalIn: .init(   // The path defining `self's` curved edge.
        x: rect.width - Self.ovalWidth,   // Align the oval's trailing edge with `self's`.
        y: (rect.height - Self.ovalHeight) / 2,   // Center oval vertically within `self`.
        width: Self.ovalWidth,
        height: Self.ovalHeight
    ))
    path.stroke()   // Draws the border of the curved edge.
    self.layer.mask={ $0.path=path.cgPath; return $0 }(CAShapeLayer())
}
```

My concern is that as far as I can see there is no guarantee that `rect` will be equal to `self.frame`; which would result in undefined behavior as far as drawing the mask goes. Is it possible that if I use `self.frame` instead of `rect` that `draw(_:)` could be called while `self.frame` has yet to be set, or has a value that is not up-to-date? — this view is laid out using AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns are only half correct. According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw):

> The portion of the view’s bounds that needs to be updated. The first
>   time your view is drawn, this rectangle is typically the entire
>   visible bounds of your view. However, during subsequent drawing
>   operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view.

Also in the docs:

> You should limit any drawing to the rectangle specified in the rect
>   parameter

draw(_:) is typically only called when the view is first displayed (not when it is added as a subview) and when setNeedsDisplay() or setNeedsDisplay(_:) is called.

As far as I know there are only two causes for concern. The first is that your view is displayed before all of you constraints are set. The second is if you call setNeedsDisplay(_:) with a specific rectangle.

Comment: I find it bad policy when writing production code to base it on what "typically" happens.